# What does the no. of bits signify in a compiler in C? Also, how does this play a role in the size of various datatypes?

Tags: c, sizeof

How does the no of bits affect things like `int`, and how to compute the size by just knowing about the compiler? For example, some books say a `16-bit` compiler will give `sizeof(int)` as `2` bytes, while a `32-bit` one will yield a different answer. So how was this `2` calculated and what is the relation with the no of bits of the compiler?

Comment: Normally "byte" means 8 bits, so 2 bytes means 8*2 = 16 bits

Comment: Usually the size of integer is equal to the width of the general purpose registers available on the target architecture(for simpler conversion to assembly and efficiency). This way a 16 bit machine has 16/8 = 2 bytes integer. Again this is just a convention. A 16 bit machine can very well have a 32 bit integer. The standard doesn't really say anything about the widths of primitive types(except char and friends). Having said that many platforms also have integer size =/= register width. One notable example is the x64 architecture on Windows. The size of int is still 4 bytes.

Comment: The number of bits is usually, but not always, the size of a processor register of the target machine (subject to minimum of 16 bit for `int`).

Comment: There is no reliable way to calculate the size of int from the architecture and platform. You will just have to look at the compiler manual.

Comment: Okay, but my question is how did that 8 come into the picture. Is it because it is the half of the no of bits of the compiler used? (Sorry for not clearly asking the question!)

Comment: There are usually (but not always) 8 bits in one byte. Bit = "binary digit".

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Okay. I got confused because in many books a 32-bit compiler shows size of int as 2, but in some websites, they show the size of int as 4 for a 32-bit compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Okay, so can a 64-bit compiler give size of int as 2 in any case?

Comment: @AJ1993 it depends on compiler to compiler. The only way to check would be `printf("%zu", sizeof(int));` (or ofcourse look at that compiler's manual).

Comment: A 32-bit compiler running on a 64-bit machine can compile code for a 16-bit `int` running on an 8-bit processor. This is called a "cross compiler".

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Okay! Thank you! Got some clarity now! :)

Comment: @WeatherVane even when compiling __for__ 64 bit a compiler can return 2 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Great example of cross-compiler. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes it can, because 16 bits is the minimum size of `int` defined in the standard, but why would you want to generate code that uses less than the typical register size?

Comment: @WeatherVane I just meant to answer *Okay, so can a 64-bit compiler give size of int as 2 in any case?* cross compilation is a little orthogonal because architecture of the compiling machine is irrelevant. Also most 64 bit platforms use 32 bit for integer. The reason for that is that operating on the 32 bit subregister is a bit cheaper. I agree though, 16 bit on 64 but platform would be very rare to see.